# R2D2 urdf moving in Rviz but not Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I can load my r2d2 urdf from the urdf tutorials in both Gazebo and Rviz. However, in RViz the model is moving in a circle and in Gazebo it is stationary.  Why is this so?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47674/r2d2-urdf-moving-in-rviz-but-not-gazebo/) by [tangell](https://answers.ros.org/users/3534/tangell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-07**:
Not enough information. How does your set up look like?

**Comment by [tangell](https://answers.ros.org/users/3534/tangell/) on 2012-11-07**:
I'm not sure what kind of information you're looking for?

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-07**:
For example, what tutorial did you follow? How do you move the models in rviz?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-07**:
Also which launch files are you running? Which ROS distribution? See http://ros.org/wiki/Support

**Comment by [tangell](https://answers.ros.org/users/3534/tangell/) on 2012-11-07**:
I'm using ROS fuerte and I followed this tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher

I'm using the state and launch file from that page. I changed model.xml to model.urdf and made the launch file look for model.urdf instead of model.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The R2D2 Tutorials publish information to /tf, which is visualized in rviz. It does NOT simulate the motors and other functionality for it to be fully simulated in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tangell](https://answers.ros.org/users/3534/tangell/) on 2012-11-07**:
So when a robot is able to be simulated in Gazebo and Rviz, what kind of extra information or files are being used?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-11-07**:
You need to specify the controllers for the different joints.

**Comment by [tangell](https://answers.ros.org/users/3534/tangell/) on 2012-11-07**:
Can you give me an example?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-11-08**:
Alas, I have not myself mastered the Gazebo half of model building. However, I can recommend checking out how other robot models do it, such as http://ros.org/wiki/erratic_description

**Comment by [tangell](https://answers.ros.org/users/3534/tangell/) on 2012-11-09**:
I found this :  http://answers.ros.org/question/9628/moving-a-robot-in-gazebo/
it looks like it might point in the right direction for that.